# Django Admin :: HTML Input

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In Django's admin panel: how do I add a form field that users can add unescaped HTML into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a standard TextField, the data gets saved unescaped. However, by default any data that is outputted in a template is [automatically escaped](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape). You can circumvent this by either disable autoescaping (bad idea!) by using the [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#safe) filter.

Comment: and if the data is outputted as json?

Comment: Depends: If you use a template to generate the JSON it's the same. If you use a JSON module like json und simplejson you have to do nothing, it will not be escaped.

Comment: btw, the problem was with moustachejs automatically escaping my data.